# How to safely change the directory of rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After creating a rails project I tried to move the project directory to another path but I encountered a problem when generating new migration

It seems like rails still looking in the **old "db"** directory.

how to solve this problem ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
16: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
15: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
14: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
13: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
11: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
10: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
 9: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
 8: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
 7: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
 6: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
 5: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
 4: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:30:in `call'
 3: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:33:in `rescue in call'
 2: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `cold_run'
 1: from /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76:in `boot_server'

/home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby on rails/my-blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76:in `spawn': No such file or directory - /home/islam/Desktop/x/Ruby/Ruby (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: please, include the error to the question.

Comment: done , the error is included

Comment: can you run this `spring restart` and then try the generate command again. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @RafayetMonon spring is not a command and it tells me to install it